# Changing number format on a specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting, number-formatting

I've searched this forum for a solution, but none of the tips helped me. Perhaps I'm way too novice to put the code together by myself.

I'm trying to set a date format of "dd.mm.yyyy" on the sheet "Sheet2" in range G3:G.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
Range("G3, G").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
```

Could you guys please point out what I'm missing?

Comment: "G3, G" or "G3:G are not valid ranges

Answer (score 1):

Due to the below issue, your code is not the right code.

1. a cell address should have both row & column details. In the code you have given, no last cell row is mentioned.
2. Use the Collan symbol ":" to select a range of cells between the first & last cell.
3. You have used "with" statement for the worksheet, but the range is not referenced to that statement. meaning, you will have to put a dot "." before the range to follow the correct practice.

Below is the corrected code.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("G3:G25").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy" 'here i am assuming G25 is the last cell
    End With
```

If you are not sure about the last cell, you can use the below code.

```
Sub Test()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("G3: " & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Address).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
```